# set a multi index in the dataframe constructor using the data-list provided to the constructor

Tags: python, pandas

I know that by using `set_index` i can convert an existing column into a dataframe index, but is there a way to specify, directly in the Dataframe constructor to use of one the data columns as an index (instead of turning it into a column).

Right now i initialize a DataFrame using data records, then i use `set_index` to make the column into an index.

```
DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':1,"c":2,'d':1},{'a':1,'b':2,"c":2,'d':2}], index= ['a', 'b'], columns=('c', 'd'))
```

I want:

```
   c  d
ab 
11  2  1
12  2  2
```

Instead i get:

```
   c  d
a  2  1
b  2  2
```

Comment: What's wrong with `pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':1,"c":2,'d':1},{'a':1,'b':2,"c":2,'d':2}]).set_index(['a','b'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
print (pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x['a'], x['b']) for x in d], names=('a','b')))
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=['a', 'b'])

d = [{'a':1,'b':1,"c":2,'d':1},{'a':1,'b':2,"c":2,'d':2}]
df= pd.DataFrame(d, 
                 index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x['a'], x['b']) for x in d], 
                                                    names=('a','b')), 
                 columns=('c', 'd'))
print (df)
     c  d
a b      
1 1  2  1
  2  2  2
```

Comment: This is a good way I agree, the only issue is my index has now lost its name. The index name gets automatically saved when converting from a column to index. And i need the index name to be saved.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Add parameter `names`, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain call `set_index` on the ctor without specifying the index and columns params:

```
In [19]:    
df=pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':1,"c":2,'d':1},{'a':1,'b':2,"c":2,'d':2}]).set_index(['a','b'])
df

Out[19]:
     c  d
a b      
1 1  2  1
  2  2  2
```

Comment: Well that would mean returning a "new" Dataframe, from an already existing DF. Granted i can do that. but i would rather call 

df.set_index(index, inplace=True) in the next line